# Complete list of my backlinks

Tags: seo, google, backlinks, disavow-links

i want to detect all my toxic backlinks. but first of all,

Do you have any idea 'how can i get complete list of my sites backlinks'? (all of them)

you know; we can check it from webmaster-tools, but i dont know if its 100% of all, or not.

i dont want to pay 300-500 euros to seo or link delete companies. can't i get a list of all my backlinks? (then, i will check one by one if its toxic or not)

Comment: Do you have a reason to do this? Have you received notices of bad back links in Webmaster Tools?

Comment: There is no such thing as a complete or even close to complete back link list except what Google offers and even that is not complete.

Comment: DisgruntledGoat: i want to check it because of possibility of algorithm penalty. i dont have any manuel penalty/error..

Comment: closetnoc: what about paid services? as like moz.com?

Answer (score 2):

Google has the most complete list of backlinks than anyone else. You could use services such as ahrefs, opensiteexplorer or semrush but they are all going to be different. Each of their crawlers might find one URL that another doesn't.

If you are serious about your backlinks your best bet is to get backlinks from all of the three services I just mentioned as well as Webmaster Tools. Compile them all into one Excel sheet and remove the duplicates.

Comment: google webmaster tools + bing control panel + yandex = %80 of all backinks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to be concerned about "toxic" backlinks to your site unless you have a good reason to believe they exist, for example Google or Bing webmaster tools specifically informs you of low quality links. See [this Google help page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en) for details.

That link also answers your specific question - it states that the download from GWT contains *"all the pages linking to your site".*

In reality, this is *all the links Google knows about*, which is all that matters. It cannot be possible to get a list of *every* link to your site - the web is simply too big!

But the file from GWT will *certainly* contain more links than any other "SEO tool" can give you so definitely don't shell out hundreds of buck for those.

Comment: i dont know why, but i fell down from 2nd page to 15 in three months :)

Answer (score 1):

You aren't going to be able to get a complete list of all your backlinks in one place. The worst place to start would be GWT. There is going to be very little useful (or even accurate information there). GWT is more useful as a venue to get communication from Google about red flags on your site and see what pages are getting indexed.

Here is a list of places to get backlinks. These guys are actually trying to go out and create an index of the internet to approximate what Google is doing.

Majestic SEO
AHREF
MOZ